# Ruby on rails devise flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise gem in my application. After logging out i redirect user to the home page. When I go to log in page again, I see "You have been logged out" message from previous session. It happens even if I refresh my home page 20 times. Here's my `devise_error_messages!` method's code:

```
def devise_error_messages!
flash_errors = []
flash_notices = []

if !flash.empty?
  flash_errors.push(flash[:error]) if flash[:error]
  flash_errors.push(flash[:alert]) if flash[:alert]
  flash_notices.push(flash[:notice]) if flash[:notice]
end

return "" if resource.errors.empty? && flash_errors.empty? && flash_notices.empty?

# not important output styling
errors = resource.errors.empty? ? flash_errors : resource.errors.full_messages
error_icon = "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&nbsp;</span>"
errors = errors.map { |msg| "<p>" + error_icon + msg + "</p>" }.join
errors = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">" + errors + "</div>" unless errors.empty?

notice_icon = "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&nbsp;</span>"
notices = flash_notices.map { |msg| "<p>" + notice_icon + msg + "</p>" }.join
notices = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">" + notices + "</div>" unless notices.empty?

html = <<-HTML
<div id="error_explanation">
  #{errors}
  #{notices}
</div>
HTML

html.html_safe
end
```

I'm using Rails 4.2.3, ruby 2.2.2 and devise 3.4.1. Is there any way to get rid of that old message? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think flash_alerts = [] required at the top and flash_alerts.push(flash[:alert]) if flash[:alert]

Comment: I don't use flash_alerts array anywhere, I push flash[:alerts] to flash_errors array. It's some modification I needed to use, not associated with the main problem

Comment: just add `flash.clear` after the assignements of the flashes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an overrided devise_error_messages! method, adjusting it for your needs:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                      :count => resource.errors.count,
                      :resource => resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end

  def devise_error_messages?
    resource.errors.empty? ? false : true
  end

end
```

Also for better understanding of what's happening, you could place a breakpoint(binding.pry) in your code and check the flash array on the controller and view rendering: https://github.com/pry/pry